# Confusing question, asyncio with a loop inside a loop

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am trying to develop a "reverse proxy" type of thing, and I am almost done. However, I have ran into an issue. I have two servers. The main server running the actual source (server A) and the proxy server which clients will connect to (server B).

Basically, my design is as follows:

After client connects to Server B (the proxy server)...

1. Client begins sending their packets to Server B.
2. Server B sends their packets to Server A
3. Server A receives their packet, parses it appropriately (this is the actual source), and then sends response packet(s) back to Server B
4. Server B receives the packet response from Server A, and sends it back to the Client.

So far, it is working fine. However, there is one major issue. The asynchronous loop can only receive one packet from Server A (the source server) per client packet. So if Server B sends one packet to Server A, Server B will only be able to receive one response packet from Server A, even if Server A wants to respond with multiple packets. I believe the read function is blocking.

I have a few files. I am running everything inside this loop:

```py
import asyncio
asyncio.run(server.loop())
```

And then this is the actual loop (it is a longer file, but I removed redundant information):

```py
    async def loop(self):
        self.server = await asyncio.start_server(self.init, self.settings['proxy']['host'], self.settings['proxy']['ports'][self.type])

        async with self.server:
            print("~Listening @ {%s:%s}" % (self.settings['proxy']['host'], str(self.settings['proxy']['ports'][self.type])))
            print()
            await self.server.start_serving()
            await self.server.serve_forever()

    async def init(self, r, w):
        await cli.client(self, r, w).connect()
```

As you can see it calls a client class, that client class contains the loop for the actual proxy file. It receives packets from the client, sends it to Server A, receives Server A's response, and sends it back to the client. This is the client class (redundant information removed)

```py
    async def connect(self):
        self.ip = self.w.get_extra_info('peername')
        self.tag = ("[%s:%s]" % (self.ip[0], str(self.ip[1])))
        self.dest['r'], self.dest['w'] = await asyncio.open_connection(host=self.host, port=self.port)

        print("NEW_CLIENT::%s" % (self.tag))

        while(not self.w.is_closing()):
            try:
                data = await self.r.readuntil(separator=b'\x00')
                if data:
                    await self.forward(data)
                else:
                    await self.disconnect()
            except asyncio.IncompleteReadError:
                await self.disconnect()

    async def forward(self, data):
        #data = data.decode("utf-8")[:-1]
        print("<= SEND_DEST::%s %s" % (self.tag, data.decode("utf-8")[:-1]))
        self.dest['w'].write(data)
        await self.dest['w'].drain()
        data = await self.dest['r'].readuntil(separator=b'\x00')
        print("=> RECV_DEST::%s => %s" % (self.tag, data.decode("utf-8")[:-1]))
        if data:
            self.w.write(data)

    async def disconnect(self):
        print("[Disconnect Client]: %s:%s" % (self.ip[0], str(self.ip[1])))
        self.w.close()
```

So far, everything works as intended. The client sends a packet to this proxy file (server B), the packet is sent to the main source (server A), the main source sends back packets to the proxy file (server B), and then finally server B sends server A's response back to the client. It is a working proxy script.

**The Problem:** With this reverse proxy, I can only receive one line at a time from the main Server A. So basically, if the client sends Server B 1 packet, this remote proxy only reads 1 response packet from Server A, even if Server A sends several response packets back. So basically, I can only read one line at a time, in the `forward()` function.

I can't really figure out what to do here, except maybe make another loop for the reading process? I don't know how I would do that though. Maybe use `run_in_executor`?

Comment: Just a hint: you almost certainly don't need another loop, nor `run_in_executor`. You might need `asyncio.create_task()` to create more than one coroutine that do their work _in parallel_.